# How to launch a subprocess with captured output, but letting the subprocess believe it isn't captured?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, stdout

Imagine launching a subprocess say `my_binary` in these two ways (I'm using bash for simplicity, but I assume this applies for other languages on POSIX systems):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# 1) inherit stdout/stderr
my_binary

# 2) explicitly capture stdout/stderr
my_binary 2>&1 > output.log
```

Often binaries behave differently when their output is captured. For instance `ls` typically disables color output with captured output, unless forced with `--color=always`.

Now consider a case where `my_binary` behaves differently under captured output, but lacks an explicit output control mechanism, i.e., the equivalent of `--color=always`. I'm trying to find out:

- What mechanisms are used internally to determine the capabilities of I/O streams?
- Is it possible to "fake" the I/O stream capabilities externally, i.e., run `my_binary` with captured output, but let it behave exactly as if the output was not captured?

Comment: [How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249723/108618)?

Comment: Thanks Kamil, that's what I was looking for. I suppose I can't mark it as duplicate because it is on a different SO site. I wasn't aware that there are two overlapping SO sites.

Comment: After a few more hours of searching... Of course there is also a question on StackOverflow: [How to trick an application into thinking its stdout is a terminal, not a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402389/1804173)